# z-index not working in a popup

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup, z-index

I having a issue with a drop down list inside a Jquery modal popup.

I wrote a customized dropdown list with `lu` and `li` tags. The position was set to `absolute`. It works perfectly fine in the other place, but when I put this component in a popup and when the dropdown list is long, the extra part will be covered by the popup, not on top of the popup.

I check the `z-index` for the popup is 1000, I tried to put much more great numbers of `z-index` value for the dropdown `lu` tag. It is still covered... Hope someone who has a lot of experiences about this could help me out, thank you so much.

```
var $dialog = $(".ui-res-offer-dialog");
$dialog.modal("show");
```

The dialog is a `<div></div>` with class `.ui-res-offer-dialog`, and there is some input fields inside the `<div>`. Below is the code generates the dropdown list. $elem is a global variable which will change based on which input field is clicked.

```
function displayFieldOptions(list) {
        if($elem != null) {
            var currentValue = $elem.val().toUpperCase();
            if("" != currentValue) {
                var optionsHtml = '<ul class="field-options-container">';
                var optionsSize = 0;

                $.each(list, function(index, value) {
                    // If the value contains the user input, and the option size is under 10, add this option
                    if(value.toUpperCase().indexOf(currentValue) >= 0 && optionsSize < 10) {
                        optionsHtml += '<li class="field-options" onclick="setFieldValue(this)">' + value + '</li>';
                        optionsSize++;
                    }
                });
                optionsHtml += "</ul>";
                $(".field-options-container").remove();
                var $optionsHtml = $(optionsHtml);
                $optionsHtml.css("width",$elem.css("width"));
                // If the input box is focused and it has options inside, display it
                if($elem.is(":focus") && optionsHtml.indexOf("setFieldValue") > 0) {
                    $elem.after($optionsHtml);
                }
            } else {
                $(".field-options-container").remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is the css code for the ul tag

```
.field-options-container {
    z-index: 3000;
    border: 1px solid #485c87;
    background: #ffffff 50% bottom repeat-x;
    color: #222222;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This is the dialog generated by the modal plugin

```
<div class="ui-res-offer-dialog modal ui-res-offer-dialog-active in" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="false" data-backdrop="static" style="display: block;">
    <div class="ui-res-offer-dialog-container">
        <!-- some input fields here, too long I can't paste all of them -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the css of the dialog tags

```
.modal {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1050;
    outline: 0;
    height: 1000px;
}
.ui-res-offer-dialog-container {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
    left: 40%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 380px;
    color: black;
}
```

For .ui-res-offer-dialog-container, even I change the height from auto to a static value, the dropdown list is still covered.

Comment: This is going to be really hard to solve without seeing any code.

Comment: Try setting your drop-down's positioning to relative. .drop-down {position: relative;}

Comment: The code is a lot, but I can describe it a little more.
There was a div like this'<div class="my-popup"><input class="my-search-filed"></input></div>`. I used `$(".my-popup").modal("show")` to display the popup, its a Jquery plugin I belive.  Then I was using Jquery to append this `<lu><li></li><li></li><li></li></lu>` under the input, the lu tags are styled as a dropdown list.  But the dropdown list has about 10 values, the input is almost at the bottom of the popup, I can only see 2 values of the dropdown, the others was out side of the popup, but they are covered by the popup not on the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to make sure the `overflow` of the overall dialog (not the list) is not set to `hidden`, which would hide anything that would normally extend out of it, and a static height (on the dialog) is not set (this is probably more likely). A high `z-index` would not be enough if either is the case.

**I presume you mean 'ul' not 'lu'?

Comment: You are right, its ul, I am sorry... :(   
We actually just want to display 10 items of the list so if I have more value, I will not generate more then 10 li tags inside. So I didn't specify the overflow and height value at all. This might be the issue here. I will try this, thank you so much. I will come back shortly.

Comment: Oh you mean the overflow and height for the dialog not the ul. Okay, I will check these. Thank you.

Comment: The height of the dialog was set to "auto"... But there will be some difficulty if I give it a static height value. Because the content of this dialog may change, then the height should change automatically to fit the content... And I tried to give it a height, and still the dropdown list is covered. Is there anything else you can think of sir? Thank you.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of, and don't take offense to this, but because you keep mis-using elements in your comments and OP, is it possible that you have left some tags open or using tags that don't exist and therefore cannot be styled appropriately? Can you edit your original post with the actual relavent code from the project?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did check the tags, they are fine, and no html or js errors in the browser. I just updated the question. I will keep trying.

Comment: I was trying to change the css in the browser... I found that if I remove the overflow hidden from the dialog, then I can see the rest of the dropdown. Did you type your first answer incorrectly? You were saying it should be set to hidden in order to display my dropdown right?  You lead me to the right way. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ha. Yeah, I meant to say, "make sure it is not set to 'hidden'".